# How to use Hangfire.MysqlStorage with .net core with MySql.Data?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, hangfire, mysql.data

I'm trying to use Hangfire with MysqlStorage in Asp.Net core project. With Hangfire.MysqlStorage 2.0 package, MysqlConnector is installed. I'm facing lot of problems with MysqlConnector and it is not very much stable. When I install Mysql.Data with this, the problem comes i.e. MySql.Data exists in two assemblies. When I try to use the older version of Hangfire.MysqlStorage 1.0.7 then the hangfire don't work and error comes as Missing method exception. Can hangfire work in .net core with Mysql.Data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed the package Hangfire.MysqlStorage to Hangfire.MySql.Core_MySql.Data and now I'm able to use MySql.Data package with Hangfire and its working fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, would like to add 'Hangfire.MysqlStorage' works until MySQL Version 5.6 it doesn't work with MySQL 8, I was getting syntax errors 
https://github.com/arnoldasgudas/Hangfire.MySqlStorage/issues/48